# Facebook Ad unable to be edited in native interface

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm running into some errors I believe are related to action_specs within adcreatives.

I'm using the Ads API to create an ad.  The creatives looks like this:

```
{
      "object_id": 1xxxxxxxxxx6, 
      "action_spec": [
        {
          "action.type": [
            "like"
          ], 
          "page": [
            1xxxxxxxxxxxxx6
          ]
        }
      ], 
      "name": "Creative Name", 
      "related_fan_page": 1, 
      "type": 25, 
      "id": "1xxxxxxxxxxxxx6"
    }
```

The AdGroup looks like this:

```
{
  "conversion_specs": [
  ], 
  "name": "AdGroup Name", 
  "tracking_specs": [
    {
      "action.type": [
        "page_engagement"
      ], 
      "page": [
        1xxxxxxxxxxxxx6
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "id": "1xxxxxxxxxxxxx6"
}
```

So I have a Sponsored Story (type 25) with one action spec (liking a page).  It creates fine with no errors coming back from the API, but when I go into the native interface and open up the Ad, I see three actions selected.

Then when I click "Save" the page throws an error. ("(#2615) Query missing object: Each action query must use at least one object.")  (Note: the error doesn't actually show up on the page, you have to look for uncaught exceptions in the debugger and dig to find it which leads me to believe there's something odd going on here).

As far as I can tell I'm following the documentation and examples.  Does anyone have any insight they could provide into what is happening and preventing the ad from being edited/saving?

Answer (score 0):

The Ads API has different functionality and options available compared to Facebook's native ads interfaces -

It's not necessarily possible to create an ad via the API and view or update it via Ad Manager or the Power Editor tool (this depends on whether your API-created ad has options not available or supported by those tools, it may work perfectly fine for other ads)